# How to get the { } on a macbook pro retina mid 2014 running Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout, macbook-pro

As the title says, i can't find the combination to get these { }.My keyboard layout is Portuguese (Portugal).

I'm using the macbook pro retina mid 2014.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination is:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>/<kbd>9</kbd>